# Android - Creating a Basketball Statistics screen

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently working on an android basketball stat tracking application.

I am using the android SDK and developing it on eclipse.

I'm to the point where we are going to need a stats screen for the game that is currently active. I need to pull stats from the game that is currently running that is outputting stats into a stat table. We are using SQLite as our database to store everything.

My problem is that I know how I can pull and count the different stats, and how to output them. But I'm thinking there is an easier way to do what I'm attempting to do.

For the stat screen activity, this is what we currently have.

[image: stats]

Don't mind the big zero in the top left, that's just a formatting issue. Don't mind the warnings either, that's because I didn't make string values for these yet.

So every single zero is its own TextView, and if a team has 20 players, that is 180 TextViews I have to populate with different numbers.

I have thought of different ways I could format the TextView ID's so I would only have to run a different code depending on the player's # for each of the 8 stats.

But in the end, I'm still using 180 different TextViews.

Is this the only way I could do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a ListView with a custom View and an Adapter, refer to this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

A Listview, because you can have 2 or 40 players.

a Custom View (in XML) so you can customize the fields / imageView / others

the Adapter "fills" the Custom View and put into the ListView

http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! I will definitely try that. This is the very first android programming I've ever done so I'm not sure what I'm doing but that sounds great. I'll let you know how it goes, thanks!